# Capillary pressure for large contact angles

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics, surface-tension, capillary-action

The capillary pressure is calculated according to the following relation.

$$P_{cap} = \dfrac{2\sigma cos\theta}{r}$$

Is this relation valid for all contact angles i.e. $\theta \lt 90^\circ$ and $\theta \gt 90^\circ$?