# Relation between surface tension and contact angle

Tags: fluid-statics, surface-tension, capillary-action

The higher the surface tension, the lower the contact angle. Is there a well defined mathematical relation between surface tension and contact angle?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Young's equation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/485895/)

Comment: Related question by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/740323/2451